# Shell script detectar APs e Mac Address

Tags: shell, scripting

Meu objetivo é desenvolver um script em ambiente Linux (Kali Linux) que automatize certas tarefas como por exemplo, enquanto executando, *detecte Access Points* próximos me mostrando a intensidade do sinal e o *Mac Address* do mesmo, assim como os clientes que estão conectados.

Não me importa tipo de encriptação pois o objetivo não é invasão e sim anti-invasão. Uma vez que eu obtenha estas informações, eu possa decidir sobre quais *APs* e clientes devo dirigir a ação de desautenticar.

Se já houver algum script assim e for possível deixar um link ou cópia do código. Fico muito agradecido. Caso os colegas não conheçam, também aceito a ajuda de alguém experiente no assunto.

Não é trabalho de faculdade e nem para fins profissionais. Apenas para uso exclusivo.

> **Obs.:** Eu já tenho um trecho de código que detecta meu *Mac address* para fazer uma comparação posteriormente e evitar que eu mesmo seja desautenticado do *AP*.

Comment: Amigo, pelo que ví, vc esta querendo o código pronto.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu... "Se alguém tiver um código pronto que atenda essas necessidades, caso possa compartilhar", ficarei feliz. Pois não vejo motivo para reinventar a roda... Mas caso isso não seja possível, ficaria muito feliz se alguém que manja de Shell Script, pudesse me ajudar com alguns insights...

Comment: Vc precisa aprender linux, comece por uma distro como ubuntu, aprendendo o básico, depois disso vc pode passar para o kali que é uma distro com muitos recursos já instalados. Caso vc sem conhecimento, pegue algum script pronto, e o mesmo de algum erro, vc não conseguira resolver o erro.
Isso que vc quer é bem simples, não fareis esse script pra vc, pois a ideia é aprender, se pegar pronto vc não vai aprender.

Comment: Colega. Já uso Kali Linux. Estou desenvolvendo um projeto pessoal baseado em Shell Script. Até já domino muitas coisas de shell scripting como por exemplo guardar valores em variáveis, estruturas de condição e repetição, mas meu problema está em usar expressão regular para trabalhar com as saídas de outros programas na console.

Comment: Se que ifconfig aplicado sobre uma placa de rede ativa me fornece o Mac Address ativo. Também sei que iwlist aplicado sobre minha placa de rede ativa, associado ao scan me fornece uma lista de access points próximos.

Comment: ok, vamos as dicas então:
vc precisa aprender principalmente sobre o comando "iw" segue a manpage --> https://linux.die.net/man/8/iw

Expressão regular vc praticamente não irá usar, apenas conhecimento básico com "grep"," egrep","awk" e "sed" será mais do que suficiente para obter o resultado que busca.

vc pode dar uma olhada nesse canal para ter o básico de shellscript --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOLPUc6oo-w&list=PLucm8g_ezqNrYgjXC8_CgbvHbvI7dDfhs

Esse é o caminho, boa sorete.

Comment: Assim que eu terminar o script, posto ele para ajudar outros e já fecho o tópico... Vlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o utilitário [`iwlist`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwlist) com o argumento `scan` para listar todos os APs dentro do alcance:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Saída:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 00:1F:F3:02:04:81
                    ESSID:"Apple Network"
                    Mode:Master
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=42/100  Signal level:-84 dBm  Noise level=-127 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C0217FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                              48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Extra:tsf=0000003d7dfe8049
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1840ms ago
          Cell 02 - Address: 00:1D:7E:F8:15:F8
                    ESSID:"42"
                    Mode:Master
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=58/100  Signal level:-73 dBm  Noise level=-127 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Extra:tsf=0000007a7d5a1b80
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1616ms ago
          Cell 03 - Address: 00:1E:E5:65:C4:89
                    ESSID:"Adkins"
                    Mode:Master
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=84/100  Signal level:-49 dBm  Noise level=-127 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Extra:tsf=000001b2460c1608
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1672ms ago
```

E pode filtrar somente as informações do `ESSID`, do `MAC Address` e informações sobre o sinal (`Quality`, `Signal level` e `Noise level`) por meio do utilitário `grep`:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep "Address\|ESSID\|Quality"
```

Saída:

```
  Cell 01 - Address: 00:1F:F3:02:04:81
            ESSID:"Apple Network"
            Quality=42/100  Signal level:-84 dBm  Noise level=-127 dBm
  Cell 02 - Address: 00:1D:7E:F8:15:F8
            ESSID:"42"
            Quality=58/100  Signal level:-73 dBm  Noise level=-127 dBm
  Cell 03 - Address: 00:1E:E5:65:C4:89
            ESSID:"Adkins"
            Quality=84/100  Signal level:-49 dBm  Noise level=-127 dBm
```

Comment: Obrigado a vocês que me orientaram. Com essas informações já consigo realizar esse projetinho...